# Setting a :has_many :through association on a belongs_to association Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through, belongs-to

I have three models, each having the following associations:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2s
  has_many :model3s
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
  has_many :model3s, :through => :model1  # will this work? is there any way around this?
end

class Model3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
  has_many :model2s, :through => :model1  # will this work? is there any way around this?
end
```

As you can see in the commented text, I have mentioned what I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just create the method to access it

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1

  def model3s
    model1.model3s
  end
end
```

Or, you can delegate to model1 the model3s method

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1

  delegate :model3s, :to => :model1

end
```

Comment: the delegation part gives me this error "Delegation needs a target. Supply an options hash with a :to key as the last argument (e.g. delegate :hello, :to => :greeter).". Let me try the method part

Comment: The first way is doing good and solves my problem. But please find some tweaks in the delegation mechanism and edit the answer. :D

Comment: use delegate :model3s, :to => :model1 instead of delegate :model3s, :as => :model1. :D works for me

Comment: You right. I need check the documentation befopre answer sometimes.

Comment: add :allow_nil => true to delegate method, because if calls delegate on a nil object ruby raises an error

Comment: As an update, since Rails 4.2 you can now perform `has_many` and `has_one` through a `belongs_to` relationship

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2s
  has_many :model3s
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :model1
 has_many   :model3s, :primary_key => :model1_id,
                      :foreign_key => :model1_id

end

class Model3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
  has_many   :model2s, :primary_key => :model1_id,  
                       :foreign_key => :model1_id
end
```

This will have active record join model2 and model3 by model1_id leaving model1 completely out of it and should be more efficient.

Comment: In the general case this would lose any conditions attached to the "has_many" definitions in Model1.  e.g. if Model1 was defined with `has_many :model2s, -> {where deleted: false}` you wouldn't pick those conditions up without writing some extra code that was potentially fragile and/or verbose.  Just something to be aware of.